# Mysql: обновление триггером своей же таблицы

Tags: mysql, sql, триггер

У меня есть таблица с платежами, где помимо суммы платежа хранится баланс человека на момент платежа. Я хотел с помощью триггера mysql сделать следующее: при удалении платежа - баланс на начало последующих проводок уменьшался на сумму удаляемого платежа.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `before_delete_payment`
BEFORE DELETE ON `payment` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    UPDATE `payment` SET `value_before` = `value_before` - OLD.`amount`
    WHERE `time` > OLD.`time`;
END
```

Но соответственно возникает ошибка, что триггер не может работать с таблицей, с которой он ассоциирован.

Как можно поступить в таком случае? Реализовывать все не в БД, отдельным запросом?

Comment: Наиболее правильным решением было бы не хранить вычисляемый текущий баланс вообще, а получать его на лету, когда он необходим. Если есть проблемы со скоростью доступа - то кешировать текущий баланс в отдельной таблице. Но на начало каждой операции его все равно стоило бы вычислять. А обновить таблицу так, как вы хотите в MySQL невозможно

Comment: И кстати, в похожей таблице у меня вообще запрещено удаление записей, только добавление. Сделали неправильную проводку - вставляйте запись на сторно. так и неверные вычисления не возможны в принципе, все происходит атомарно одной операцией и история действий с балансом сохраняется, что полезно при разборе полетов

Comment: Спасибо за советы! Я думал насчет того, чтобы не удалять ошибочные платежи, а проводить новую проводку с типом "отмена платежа". При такой схеме не будет непредсказуемых уходов человека в минус. Но тогда мне нужно будет создать поле наподобие cancelled_payment_id, в котором будет храниться идентификатор-ссылка на отмененный платеж. Либо еще вариант - создать поле is_deleted типа tinyint(1), помечать в нем удаленные платежи и, соответственно, не учитывать их. Какой по вашему мнению вариант лучше?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Выполняйте удаление платежа не простым запросом, а хранимой процедурой. А в ней реализуйте всю необходимую логику. Шаблонно:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE delete_payment(p_id bigint)
BEGIN
DECLARE p_time DATETIME;
DECLARE p_amount CURRENCY;
SELECT p.`time`, p.amount 
    INTO p_time, p_amount 
    FROM payment p 
    WHERE p.id = p_id;
UPDATE payment 
    SET value_before = value_before - p_amount 
    WHERE `time` > p_time;
DELETE FROM payment 
    WHERE `time` = p_time;
END;
```

Ну и неплохо бы всё это в транзакцию завернуть - а ну как не пройдёт какое действие...

Comment: Но вообще абсолютно согласен с **Mike** - ну не дело таскать рассчитываемый баланс как статические данные.